Visual Studio Package References Keep Going Missing
Every time I rebuild a WPF project in Visual Studio 2022 the package references break and I get the error that "Some assembly references are missing. Building to restore the NuGet cache might resolve this issue."
I then have to right click the solution and Restore NuGet packages and the solution is fine. Until the next time I debug or build the solution. Any ideas on what may be wrong? I've already updated/repaired my VS installation.

what is your current vs 2022 version? I used vs2022 community17.11.3 and it is normal. And if you create an empty wpf  app, does the error will occur?

I'm currently on V17.11.4.
I haven't tried an empty/new WPF project but its also happening in non-WPF projects.

Your problem may be related to your environment, some packages is deleted automatically after you close the vs. I have two suggestions, a. please set a new package resource and obvious the package if will be deleted b. please check if your system has the antivirus software or you could change another machine to see if the problem exists.
